# Credential Popup is when using displayReplyForm

Tags: office-js

I am working on an email template Outlook Add-in. From my add-in I am trying to reply with content and attachments to the selected email.

This is working fine everywhere except INSTALLED Outlook. When I click on my Add-in's reply button, a popup comes and asks for credentials.

This only happening when inserting content with attachments.

I am using these following office APIs :

```js
if (Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm) {
    outlookAppService.replyForm(content, attachemnts);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sk, what version of Outlook are you running? Can you confirm if the problem happens with this code as well:

Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyForm(
{
  'htmlBody' : 'hi',
  'attachments' :
  [
    {
      'type' : Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentType.File,
      'name' : 'squirrel.png',
      'url' : 'http://i.imgur.com/sRgTlGR.jpg'
    }
  ]
});

Comment: I am using version 17.0.5 and its not working with above code as well